# Can multiple threads run in parallel (not context switching) in multi core processor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have been reading that if there are say 2 threads and 2 cores , then each thread if allocated to different cores , they will be able to run concurrently or at the exact same time . Lets consider 2 threads T1 , T2 with run time of 10 sec each.

**Let's consider Single core first :**

If these 2 threads were to run in a single core, they would be running by context switching which will of course not be parallel execution but sequential, the thread scheduler will pick one and assign a slot to run. So in single-core, it can't be possible that T1 is running at 10:00:00, and T2 is also  running at 10:00:00 concurrently. So here run time of both threadsis 20sec

**Now consider multi core:**

Lets say T1 begins running on core 1 at 10:00:00 am
Then is it possible that T2 also starts to run on core 2 at exactly 10:00:00 am ?

If yes , this simply means that here the run time is halved - so total time taken to run both threads on multicore is 10 secs?
I highly doubt this but this is what I am reading , please clarify

Comment: Yes.  Java threads really can run in parallel.  Whether processing time will *really* be cut in half depends on details of the application; e.g. whether contention over locks, memory contention, etc.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: depends on the task scheduler.

Comment: You may look at the libs like this https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity But a regular application doesn't really require such low-level tricks to be applied. We use them when microseconds latency is critical. But in that case, all of your app should be designed/developed with respect to the latency. For example, you must not (re)allocate new memory on the hot/main path to prevent GC pauses, but use polling, preallocated and reusable buffers etc.etc. So, in the most practical cases don't care about scheduling and context switching at all. All this machinery works quite well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, multiple cores can run threads simultaneously i.e parallel execution of multiple threads is possible if we have multiple cores.
So it may happen that in your case, T1 and T2 runs on the exact same time, depending on the scheduler.

In single core though, because it can only run single thread at a time, it has to stop processing the first thread to give chance to second thread, before giving chance to thread T2, it saves the state of T1 and switches over to T2 this in fact is Context switching.

You can check this by running a simple program of starting 2 or more threads and see if they prints the exact almost similar timestamp or not.

Comment: I would add a note that just because your machine has multiple cores does *not* mean that your two Java threads will run on two different cores separately. Your two threads might run on the same core. Which cores are used to execute which thread, and for how long before switching intermittently to other threads, is all up to the JVM and the host operating system. And the scheduling behavior may change as runtime conditions change, such as number of other threads competing for CPU core access. This scheduling behavior is transparent to us Java programmers, with no way for us to influence.

Comment: Agreed that it depends upon the scheduler and the env